# Sharing dynamic data between two controllers with service AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, controller

I have two angular services that need to share models (a list of messages and an individual message), which they get from a call to our API. The service is as follows:

```
angular.module('CmServices', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Messages', function ($resource, $routeParams, $rootScope) { 

    var data = {};

    data.rest = $resource(url, {}, {
            query: {method:'GET', params: params},
            post: {method:'POST', params: params}
        });

    // Trying to set this through a call to the API (needs to get param from route)
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
            var messages = data.rest.query({m_gid: $routeParams.gid}, function () { 
                data.messages = messages;
            });
    });

    return data;    
});
```

and the controllers are:

```
function MessagesCtrl ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, Messages) {
   $scope.messages = Messages.messages;
}

function MessageCtrl ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, Messages) {
   $scope.messages = Messages.messages[0];
}
```

But neither of the controllers update when the data loads from the REST API (I've logged the data coming back, and it definately does).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of assigning a new array to `data.messages` like this:

```
data.messages = messages
```

use [angular.copy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) instead, which will populate the same array:

```
angular.copy(messages, data.messages)
```

That way, the controllers will see the update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a different version of `data` to each controller. I would place `messages` in $rootScope. So

```
data.rest.query({m_gid: $routeParams.gid}, function () { 
            $rootScope.messages = messages;
        });
```

Incidentally, what is the purpose of setting the return value of `data.rest.query` to `var messages`? That variable gets blown as soon as you leave the function.