# AngularJS: ng-repeat with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a simple AngularJS app, but I couldn't solve a problem regarding services, ng-repeat and dynamically added data.

**What I'm trying to do**

My page is splitted into few countrollers. 
In the `homeController` I have a text field and a button. When I press the button I'm doing an API call to the server, the server returns JSON and I'm setting the data to `Storage` service. In this part everything is OK - The server returns data as it should and the data is setted to the service and I'm getting `console.log('Data set!');` in the Storage service. In the second controller ( `slidesController` ) I'm having a `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-controller="slidesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="current in paragraphs"> test </div>
</div>
```

And as you can see in my code below, `paragraphs` is binded to `Storage.data` value in `slidesCtrl`

So, when a user enter something in the box and press the button (homeCtrl), the server should pass the returned data to `Storage` service and render the data using ng-repeat (slideCtrl). If I hardcode the data in Storage server with [2, 3, 4, 5] for example, everything is ok ( I'm getting test 4 times, because of ng-repeat ), but if the data is taken with api call, ng-repeat isn't working.

**Code**

```
App.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Api) {...

    $scope.onprocess = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;

        Api(.....);
    }
});

App.controller('slidesCtrl', function ($scope, Storage) {


    $scope.paragraphs = Storage.data.paragraphs; // NOT WORKING IF DATA IS DYNAMICALLY ADDED

    $scope.paragraphs = Storage.test; // IF DATA IS PREDEFINED EVERYTHING IS FINE


});

App.factory('Api', function ($http, Storage) {
    return function (data) {
        $http.post('/api', {
            url: data.url,
            analyze: 0
        }).success(function (res) {....
            Storage.set(res);....
        }).error(function () {....
        });
    };
});

App.factory('Storage', function () {
    var output = {};

    var set = function (data) {
        output = data;
        console.log('Data set!');
    };

    return {
        set: set,
        data: output,
        test: [1, 2, 3]
    };
});
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or a plunk...

Comment: This is already solved. I can't mark the answer till tomorrow. @Abilash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found

```
angular.copy(data, output);
```

as solution.

You can see more information on this topic
[Sharing dynamic data between two controllers with service AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703470/sharing-dynamic-data-between-two-controllers-with-service-angularjs)

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is due to the lag in a `AJAX` call and angular executes the service before a `AJAX` call. As none of the scopes are changing, angular is not detecting a change and hence its not reflecting on your

## **Possible Solution**

Use a getter in Storage service to get the paragraphs and call that getter method from `slidesCtrl`, like this.

```
App.controller('slidesCtrl', function($scope, Storage) {
    $scope.paragraphs = Storage.getParagraphs();
});
```

And in your service, you can use it like this.

```
App.factory('Storage', function() {
    var output = {};

    var set = function(data) {
        output = data;
        console.log('Data set!');
    };

    return {
        set: set,
        getParagraphs: function () {
            return output && output.paragraphs;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This solution could fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you've defined your `Storage` service.

In the `set` function, you're assigning directly to the `output` local variable, which will not automatically update the `data` property of the object the factory returns.

To illustrate the problem:

```
var output = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
function set(somenewdata) {
  output = somenewdata;
}
var obj = {data: output};
// obj == {data: {foo: 1, bar: 2}}

set({baz: 3});

// output == {baz: 3}
// but, obj == {data: {foo: 1, bar: 2}}
```

So if you change your Storage service to something like:

```
App.service('Storage', function() {
  this.data = {};
  this.set = function(newdata) {
    this.data = newdata;
  };
});
```

When a controller binds a property to `Storage.data`, the data will actually be updated.