# ng-repeat with dynamic ng-include and template variables scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

When ng-repeat is having dynamic ng-include with variables, it is not taking variables properly.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zGj9Wd8AVzG1aA9vARUn?p=preview).

main html code

```
<table style>
  <tr>
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Teacher</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat="val in data">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div ng-include src="'profile.html'" onLoad="profile=val.student"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div ng-include src="'profile.html'" onLoad="profile=val.teacher"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

profile.html code

```
<span>Id - {{profile.id}}</span>
<span>Name - {{profile.name}}</span>
```

You can see at link without ng-include it works perfect.

P.S. This is prototype of what I am actually trying to achieve.
Mainly I am having problem with variables used in dynamic ng-include present in ng-repeat.

I have checked similar questions like below but not getting any answers.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929999/ng-repeat-with-ng-include-not-working) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811948/different-ng-includes-on-the-same-page-how-to-send-different-variables-to-each) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736854/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-dynamic-data)

Comment: your saying that you cant see data under with ng-include right??

Comment: @SaEChowdary: Yes

Comment: ng-include does create a "new scope". https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include. Problem here is that first you are setting option = val.student then profile= val.teacher. profile is getting overrided. Did you try creating a directive with isolate scope. So that you dont need to use both ng-include and ng-if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-include` directive does not create a new `$scope` object, but prototypically inherits it, so your `profile` is overwritten with another value.

So first you say `profile=theStudent` and then you overwrite it with `profile=theTeacher`, therefore in both templates it is always set to the teacher.

There is a little 'hack' to fix this by adding the `ng-if="true"`, which creates a new `$scope` object:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="val in data">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div ng-include src="'profile.html'"
                 onLoad="profile=val.student"
                 ng-if="true"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-include src="'profile.html'" 
                 onLoad="profile=val.teacher"
                 ng-if="true"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

See [this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3aufD0lcoY042SDyB7x?p=preview)

Comment: This works fine. Is there any way without hack? @devqon

Comment: @SomnathMuluk yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using both `ng-include` and `ng-if` directives to achieve what you want, you can create a simple `profile` directive with isolated scope and pass data into it.

[plucker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XINmpHPnRZRzRarU3mB3?p=preview)

```
angular.module('ng-include-example', []).
controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {

  var data = [
       {
         "student" : { "id":11, "name": "John" },
         "teacher" : { "id" : 21, "name": "Mike"}
       },
       {
         "student" : { "id":12, "name": "Tony" },
         "teacher" : { "id" : 22, "name": "Jack"}
       },
       {
         "student" : { "id":13, "name": "Cris" },
         "teacher" : { "id" : 23, "name": "Anthony"}
       },
       {
         "student" : { "id":14, "name": "Greg" },
         "teacher" : { "id" : 24, "name": "Reva"}
       }

    ];

    $scope.data = data;

})
.directive("profile", function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      profile: "="
    },
    templateUrl: "profile.html"
  }
});

<div>
  Using Directive
  <table style>
      <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody ng-repeat="val in data">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <profile profile = "val.student"></profile>
          </td>
          <td>
            <profile profile = "val.teacher"></profile>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create second html as profile.html and after your code will like :

**index.html**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="val in data">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div ng-include src="'profile.html'" onLoad="profile=val.student"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-include src="'profile2.html'" onLoad="profile2=val.teacher"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

**profile2.html**

```
<span>Id - {{profile2.id}}</span>
<span>Name - {{profile2.name}}</span>
```

Comment: This will force you to maintain 2 templates with the same content

Comment: I don't want to have 2 templates. This is prototype. I have long html in template.